# C# Matching letters, numbers and special character in regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following `Regex`:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}
```

and it matches perfectly with a string like this: `AB1234`. But I have to improve this `Regex` to match with these specific rules:

- The string must have only **two** sharps (##) between each group (`AB1234##AB1234`)
- It may have 8 groups of string (`AB1234##AB1234##AB1234##AB1234##AB1234##AB1234##AB1234##AB1234`)
- Regardless the number of groups, the last one cannot have the sharps (##) at the end. So, if I have 3 groups, it will looks like this: `AB1234##AB1234##AB1234`

If I use the sample string from the second bullet point, my `Regex` will match with the pattern, but in this case it doesn't validade the characters between each group.

Can anyone help me to improve this Regex?

Comment: To provide meaningful feedback, I would likely just split on `##` then apply the simple regex to each item in the array.

Comment: @Travis Yes, you're right, but I have to validate the full string instead of each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}##){0,7}([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}##){0,7}([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})
```

Comment: If I put one more group at the end, it validates. Actually, it finds 2 groups.

Comment: No, I added one more `##AB1234` at the end, and it continue validating. If I start your pattern with `^` and finish with `$`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `Regex` and `LINQ` then use an extension method like this:

```
public static bool Validate(this string source)
{
    string pattern = "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}";
    return !source.StartsWith("##") &&
           !source.EndsWith("##") &&
           source.Split(new[] {"##"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .All(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern));
}
```

Usage:

```
bool t1 = "AB1234##AB1234".Validate(); // true
bool t2 = "AB1234##AB1234##AB1234".Validate(); // true
bool t3 = "AB1234##AB1234##" // false
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but I really need to use regex to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})(?:##(?:[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})){0,7}$
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^
          (1)                    (2)            (3)
```

1. Match at least one string that begins with two capital letters that is followed by 4 decimal digits.
2. Optionally follow that from zero to 7 times by `##` and a repetition of the first match.

**Result:** *(`*` indicates a match)*

```
* AB1234
  AB1234x
* AB1234##AB1234
* AB1234##AB1234##AB1234
  AB1234##AB1234##AB1234x
```

See the [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bJ0xY9).

**Note:** This answer is quite similar to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23298834/1497596). However, the answer here begins with the assumption that *at least one* sequence of `AB1234` is present. And it then allows for the *possibility* that it is followed zero to 7 times by `##AB1234`. In the end, both regex expressions are fine. It comes down to personal preference.

Also note that I used non-capturing groups `(?:...)` to avoid the unnecessary overhead of creating capture groups that aren't needed in this situation. (Capture groups are also known as back-references.)